# User profiles as VHDX files - paging operation errors

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, terminal-server, vhdx

Hello we have this terminal server on w2k12. Users login and have their profile mounted as virtual disk from VHDX file with filename like this C:\Users\Public\Documents\RDS_UserProfileDisks\UVHD-S-1-5-21-3626241538-2602771230-459845379-52949.vhdx
I can see these as "user disk" with blue icons in disk management.
We started to get incidents from our monitoring related to eventlogs
An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk5\DR5 during a paging operation.
or
An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk3\DR74 during a paging operation.
it is always this mounted VHDX from various users (maybe just a few).
Can it be a problem on a physical drive (it's virtual server on VMWare host) or is there some problem in the VHDX file itself? How can I do some check or fix of this drive mounted for user? It does not have a letter. Can I mount the VHDX and assign it a letter when user is not logged on and perform chkdsk on it?

Answer (score 0):

From [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff360721(v=exchg.140).aspx):

> This Error event indicates that an error was detected on a physical
>   hard disk during a disk paging operation. This problem occurs if an
>   I/O operation to a hard disk is unsuccessful. If an I/O operation to a
>   hard disk is unsuccessful, the Windows operating system logs Event ID
>   51 in the System log.

So, somehow your VHDX file has I/O operation failing. What you can do now?

- be sure that your underlying physical disks/controller are healthy
- check VHDX file consistency using this powershell command: `Get-VMHardDiskDrive <vmname> | test-vhd` (give a look [here](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/testing-and-validating-hyper-v-vhdvhdx-files/) for more information)
- check filesystem consitency *inside* the VHDX file, using `chkdsk`

Comment: more questions: how do I see which logged user is having which VHDX file mapped. Can I do this test on a live mounted VHDX?

Comment: unfortunately there is no Hyper-V role installed there and we don't seem to have it on any other server... so I can't use these cmdlets :-\